# Using invite endpoint to share with specific users

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to share a document in OneDrive by providing access to specific people across orgs.  While I'm able to use the **[/invite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_invite?view=odsp-graph-online)** endpoint to provide access, sometimes I am not aware whether a given email address is entitled to receive access.  For instance, let's say:

- A user from org-1 is sharing a file with three email IDs
- Two email IDs belong to same org-1
- But the third email ID belongs to org-2, which is not entitled to receive access as per org-1's policy

When I dispatch a request to `/invite` with the three email IDs, the whole request fails i.e. none receive access to the file.

Is it possible to have partial fulfilment?  i.e. the entitled users of org-1 are given access but the user from org-2 is denied access, while the response returned is 200?

Also is this possible in Sharepoint as well?

Comment: No, you cannot make it partially success on the server side but you can validate if the given accounts are from your organization on your side(writing code) and then remove that and send the request. If you want to send it to other organizations as well you need to configure it on that site where you want to share data with.

Comment: Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot make it partially success on the server side but you can validate if the given accounts are from your organization on your side(writing code) and then remove that and send the request. If you want to send it to other organizations as well you need to configure it on the tenant or site where you want to share data with.